# Stored Procedure to create cumulative sums

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, firebird2.5

I'm trying to write Firebird stored procedure, which returns me cumulative sums for twelve months grouped by another two fields.
For now I created something like this:

```
SET TERM ^ ;

CREATE PROCEDURE A_OBRATZISKKUM(
  START_YEAR INTEGER,
  END_YEAR INTEGER)
RETURNS(
  OBRAT DOUBLE PRECISION,
  MESIC INTEGER,
  ROK INTEGER,
  SECURITYUSER_ID TYPE OF ID COLLATE WIN1250,
  FIRM_ID TYPE OF ID COLLATE WIN1250)
AS
DECLARE VARIABLE act_month INTEGER = 1;
begin
    for select
        sum(AO.Obrat), :act_MONTH, :start_YEAR, AO.SecurityUser_ID,
            AO.Firm_ID
    from A_OBRATYKUMHIST_TEMP AO
    where
        AO.Rok = :start_year
        and AO.Mesic <= :act_month
    group by
        AO.SecurityUser_ID, AO.Firm_ID
    into :obrat, :mesic, :rok, :securityuser_id, :firm_id
    do
    act_month = :act_MONTH + 1;
    suspend;
end^

SET TERM ; ^
```

But when I run it I get only one row with weird sum. What's wrong on my code?

EDIT1.
I come out from this sql query:

```
select
        sum(AO.Obrat), *1*, 2012, AO.SecurityUser_ID,
            AO.Firm_ID
    from A_OBRATYKUMHIST_TEMP AO
    where
        AO.Rok = 2012
        and AO.Mesic <= *1*
    group by
        AO.SecurityUser_ID, AO.Firm_ID
```

When I take for example month number 3, I get sum of all previous months grouped by `securityuser_id` and `firm_id`.
But if I want to get sums for all months, then I have to run this twelve times with replacing **1** for **2**, then for **3**, then ........
At the end I get cumulative sums splits up to months, years, users and firms.

Answer (score 2):

A `DO` is followed by either a single statement, or by a block. You are currently doing a single `SUSPEND` instead of multiple suspends as your intention is. Instead of

```
FOR SELECT ...
DO
   statement;
SUSPEND;
```

You need to do

```
FOR SELECT ...
DO
BEGIN
   statement;
   SUSPEND;
END
```

Also the statement `act_month = :act_MONTH + 1;` should be `act_month = act_MONTH + 1;` (no colon `:`)

### The running sum

The running sum can be achieved by self-joining for all months `<=` the current month and summing over that:

```sql
SELECT SUM(AO2.Obrat), AO.Mesic, AO.Rok, AO.SecurityUser_ID, AO.Firm_ID
FROM A_OBRATYKUMHIST_TEMP AO
INNER JOIN A_OBRATYKUMHIST_TEMP AO2
    ON AO2.Rok = AO.Rok AND AO2.Mesic <= AO.Mesic
WHERE AO.Rok = 2012
GROUP BY AO.Mesic, AO.Rok, AO.SecurityUser_ID, AO.Firm_ID
```

Note this only works within the same year, you'd need to modify the join condition if you need to sum over multiple years.

Comment: Great, now I get multiple rows. But I still have problem with months. Now month is increases with each row by one... But I need to get sums for every `securityuser` and `firm` in first month and after then increase month value.. What I have to edit to get it right results?

Comment: @Sk1X1 That month increases by `1` is simply what your current code does (`act_month = act_MONTH + 1;`). If you don't want that you should change your code; as I don't entirely understand what you want I can't tell you what you need to change. Maybe you should simply remove `:act_month` and `:start_YEAR` from your `SELECT`-clause and replace them with `AO.Mesic` and `AO.Rok`?

Comment: I edited my question, I hope it will help to understand what I need.

Comment: I know about running sums, but in my case I can't use it. That's why I want to use month by month summation.

Comment: As I understand the term 'cumulative sum' it is a running total, but if you want by month I don't understand the problem: just do `SELECT SUM(obrat), mesic, rok, ... FROM ... GROUP BY mesic, rok, ...`